# What is difference between @SpyBean and @MockBean in Mockito?

Tags: mocking, mockito, spring-test

What is the difference between the `@SpyBean` and `@MockBean` annotations in Spring?

I have already gone through the JavaDoc but didn't get the difference. If possible please give an example when to use *MockBean* and when *SpyBean*.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

A **mock** (no matter if we talk about *ordinary* objects or beans) is simply an "empty shell".

That mock object doesn't have *any* relation to the underlying production code. It is an object that *looks* like being an object of class X. But none of the methods or fields that X has do "really" exist on that mocked thing.

Whereas a **spy** *wraps* around an *existing* object of your class under test. Meaning: when you create a spy, you can decide if method calls going to the spy should be "intercepted" (then you are using the spy as if it would be a mock); or be "passed through" to the actual object the spy wraps around.

See [here](http://javapointers.com/tutorial/difference-between-spy-and-mock-in-mockito/) for further reading.

Comment: Thanks but couldn't get a clear idea. Can you elaborate more why spybean is like partial mockbean what is limitation of spybean?

Comment: Point is: this is documented all over the place. Simply read thee link I provided; or that other link I just added. A *spy* is more than a *mock*, so if at all, the mock is "limited" here. I hope this is enough to make my answer acceptable ... as said: don't expect me to repeat descriptions that are documented in many many places already.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Sorry, I can't help here. We are writing all our tests the same way, and just recently moved to JUnit5 ... never came across that error ;-(

Comment: @Ewoks Thanks. Obviously, that link is broken now. I simply removed it from the answer.