# Simulate jdbcTemplate query Exception with Spy (junit5)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, spy, junit-jupiter

I'm using Spy and not Mock because I want the regular functionality in other methods.
I want to simulate an exception while calling jdbcTemplate query.

JdbcTemplate.query prototype is `public <T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper) throws DataAccessException` and I call it like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select 1 from dual", new SingleColumnRowMapper<>());
```

Here is my spy decalration:

```
@SpyBean
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

And here is the test:

```
@Test
void testDbIsDown() {
    when(jdbcTemplate.query(anyString(),any(SingleColumnRowMapper.class)))
            .thenThrow(new DataAccessResourceFailureException("s"));
    Health health = dbServiceValidator.health();
    assertThat(health.getStatus().getCode())
            .isEqualTo(Health.down().build().getStatus().getCode());
}
```

Running the “when” throw an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RowMapper is required` While it’s works fine with @MockBean (instead of SpyBean that I want).

Why it’s working with mock but not with spy? What should I do to make it work with @Spy?

P.S. Same behavior with

```
when(jdbcTemplate.query(anyString(),any(RowMapper.class)))
        .thenThrow(DataAccessException.class);
```

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999517/what-is-difference-between-spybean-and-mockbean-in-mockito), hope it is helpful.

Comment: @Hantsy Thank you! After reading I understand I really not throw an exception with mock, just do nothing. So Actaully I need to understand how to mock JdbcTemplate.query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you using Spring Boot @MockBean or @SpyBean, both are Spring aware.

To understand Mockito mock and spy, check the [Mockito series](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series) from Baeldung, esp. [Injecting Mockito Mocks into Spring Beans](https://www.baeldung.com/injecting-mocks-in-spring).

I have written [a simple testing code sample](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-playground/blob/master/jdbc-ds-vanilla/src/test/java/com/example/demo/jdbc/JdbcPostRepositoryTest.java) of using Mockito and Spring(not Spring Boot), **spy on the real instance, and mock and replace methods by stubbing**.

The usage of `doNoting`, `doAnswer`, `doReturn`, `doThrow` are similar, call these methods on stubbing behaviors to return a result before executing the method of the spy object.

If you are interested, check the testing code samples about Mockito from my github, eg. [this test](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-jwt-sample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostControllerTest.java).